# Can I make a Comment-box with reStructuredText?

Tags: comments, restructuredtext

I have created a simple website with reStructuredText and am wondering if it is possible to create a comment-box on it.
And if it is possible how to do this, or where to find the information.

I have looked around the internet but can not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the list of [contributed extensions for Sphinx](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/default/), there is the [disqus](https://github.com/Robpol86/sphinxcontrib-disqus) extension.

If you prefer another comment system, you can use that extension as a base and modify it to create your own.